# wired network causes hadoop delay

Tags: hadoop

When I am connected to my wired network and try to run a hadoop job (even a simple ls) hadoop needs about a minute or more to start the job.If I disconnect from the network hadoop starts immediately.What should I check to resolve this problem?

Comment: We need more information than this. Are you using Hadoop in standalone, pseudo-distributed, or fully distributed?

Comment: Hi!I m using hadoop in a single node cluster based on michael-noll's tutorial.